# Ansible: Unspecified GSS failure: Minor code may provide more information, no Kerberos credentials available

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I have setup my Ansible Tower and Windows Kerberos / Active Directory authentication as specified [here](http://hindenes.com/trondsworking/2015/07/27/ansible-and-windows-configuring-kerberosactive-directory-authentication/). It is the same procedure explained in the official documentation too. For information here is what I did -

1. Installed the suggested Kerberos packages in the Ubuntu server
2. Edited the configuration files as suggested

I could verify that my configuration is working fine by running the kinit command as suggested -

```
kinit -C username@DOMAIN.COM
```

The klist command run after that showed the expected information

```
klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000
Default principal: username@DOMAIN.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
2016-05-03T10:59:04  2016-05-03T20:59:04  krbtgt/DOMAIN.COM@DOMAIN.COM
    renew until 2016-05-04T10:58:59
```

My Ansible Tower inventory contains just one VM, where under the variables in host properties, I have specified the following details -

```
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_port: "5986"
ansible_ssh_user: username@DOMAIN.COM
```

I suppose the password is not necessary since the ticket is obtained through the kinit command. I have tried adding the password above by specifying *ansible_ssh_pass* but that didn't help.

Now when I run the 'Job Template' it fails instantly with this message.

```
TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
fatal: [VM-NAME]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "kerberos: (('Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information', 851968), ('No Kerberos credentials available', -1765328243)), plaintext: 401 Unauthorized."}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: this seems like a somewhat specific issue to a relatively new feature in Tower. have  you tried emailing support@ansible.com?

Comment: No, I haven't emailed them. I am using the free tier (up to 10 users) since it's under review / experimentation. Do you have any suggestions on how can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: I have now updated both the tower version and ansible version. The behaviour is still the same.

Comment: Any solution found?

Comment: @ShacharHamuzimRajuan, I abandoned this approach and continued with a local account based authentication.

Answer (score 8):

I have run into a similar issue with approx. 10% of the servers in my environment:

```
"msg": "kerberos: authGSSClientStep() failed: (('Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information', 851968), ('Server not found in Kerberos database', -1765328377))",
```

The cause of this was that there was a `PTR` record configured but it was incorrect or had a duplicate `PTR` record.

You can check this in bash via the `host` command or in PowerShell via the `Resolve-DnsName`.

Example:

Check DNS Record

```
host {{ Server FQDN }}
```

Check Reverse DNS Record based on the output from previous DNS lookup:

```
host {{ Returned IP from Normal DNS lookup }}
```

**Please note:** No PTR Record is OK but an incorrect or duplicate PTR Record can cause issues.

Comment: Multiple PTR records indeed causing trouble - Thanks for chipping in.

Comment: Thanks! I also had multiple PTR records for several hosts. Removing the wrong ones made it work again.

Answer (score 0):

as remarked https://medium.com/@ripon.banik/ansible-windows-domain-authentication-1531d1d256c3

> Make sure the Windows Host is joined to the Domain and ansible_host in the inventory is setup using FQDN of the host.

normally I fill the inventory file out with IP's, changing this to the FQDN solved this issue for me..

also more info here: https://groups.google.com/g/ansible-project/c/tdDj4pabj30

Answer (score -3):

For any future lurkers to this issue... Set this as admin from a command prompt on your windows client:

```
winrm set winrm/config/service '@{AllowUnencrypted="true"}'
```

Comment: this looks so dangerous... I doubt this is the right solution to this problem

Comment: dangerous is relative. it's less severe if the network is isolated, well protected (but it can be severe!)